# iPhone & Google Places API

Tags: iphone, google-places-api

I am using Google place API in my application. Well, its working fine and giving response for some places. But for some places, its giving "ZERO RESULTS".

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis./maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=5000&types=&name=%@&sensor=false&key=fgewffefewweweewfe",mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude,mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude,searchPlace.text]];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *connect=  [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Can anyone give me an idea where I am getting wrong?

Comment: Thank u very much for editing.Could u help me on it?

Comment: how about providing examples of inputs where you are getting "Zero Results"?

Answer (score 0):

If the location name is not valid it will give you zero results & in some cases because of extra spaces in the string you will get URL as null. So update your code as I mentioned below and check it out.

```
NSString *googleApi = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis./maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=5000&types=&name=%@&sensor=false&key=fgewffefewweweewfe",mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude,mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude,searchPlace.text];

NSString *finalURL = [googleApi  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:finalURL];

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *connect=  [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

It may work for you.